# SQL Query for this requirement

Tags: mysql, ios, sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite DB with tables  `sample` ,`surveytype` and `status` .All 3 tables primary key id is set as foreignkey to table 'Operation".Please see the scema in the following image

[image]

My `operation` table has hence values

[image]

and sample as

[image]

and status

[image]

and survey type as

[image]

**REQUIRED**

What i need to achieve is

[image]

From the operation table get information of **status id** and show it for specific buildings for all survey types.

**Tried**

I found a way by which to loop via program getting all the sample ids and all survey typeids in and get individual statusids as

```
for all sampleid in sample table
{
   for all statustypeid in statustype table
   {  
      select statusid from operation where sampleid = 2 and surveytypeid=1
    }
}
```

Is there a better option by sql single query to generate the table with all the values

Note : Using sqlite,for ios app

Comment: Nice representation +1. which software you use to display sql schema?

Comment: Schema Diagram : Valentina studio,Data representation :Sqlitemanager, working on mac OS X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want one column for each survey type.
This is not possible to achieve directly because SQLite does not have pivot functions.

You need to do two steps.
First, get all the survey types:

```
SELECT ID, Longname FROM SurveyType
```

Then, use those values to construct a query with one subquery for each survey type column, like the following:

```
SELECT BuildingName_EN AS 'Building Name',
       BuildingID AS 'Building id',
       (SELECT StatusID FROM Operation
        WHERE SampleID = Sample.ID AND SurveyTypeID = 1) AS 'Survey 1',
       (SELECT StatusID FROM Operation
        WHERE SampleID = Sample.ID AND SurveyTypeID = 2) AS 'Survey 2',
       (SELECT StatusID FROM Operation
        WHERE SampleID = Sample.ID AND SurveyTypeID = 3) AS 'New Survey 3'
FROM Sample
```

Comment: Thank you .but if i have more values in the survey type ?Is there some way i can manipulate the names of columns in a generic manner?

Comment: That is what pivot functions would be for, if the database had them.

Comment: So in sqlite this is the only option ?

Comment: Yes, you have to create the query dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: why is Operation.StatusID of type Text, when it's filled with values from integer field?
The same may be asked about RegionID, but as Region table is not listed here I can't tell, maybe you need Text in that particular case. But having Operation.StatusID as Text is totally unjustified and will give you performance penalty.

Nevertheless, there is an old trick, called pivoting but it will work only for a fixed number of columns, in your case - Surveys:

```
SELECT
  Sample.BuildingID,
  MAX(Sample.BuildingName_EN) BuildingID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Operation.SurveyTypeID=1 THEN Operation.StatusID ELSE " " END) AS Survey1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Operation.SurveyTypeID=2 THEN Operation.StatusID ELSE " " END) AS Survey2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Operation.SurveyTypeID=3 THEN Operation.StatusID ELSE " " END) AS Survey3
FROM Sample,Operation
WHERE Operation.SampleID=Sample.ID
GROUP BY Sample.BuildingID
```

Update:
To ensure expandability of this solution, you will have to generate this query each time before use with another one:

```
SELECT '  SELECT Sample.BuildingID,MAX(Sample.BuildingName_EN) BuildingID,'
UNION ALL
SELECT concat(' MAX(CASE WHEN Operation.SurveyTypeID=',SurveyType.ID,' THEN Operation.StatusID ELSE " " END) AS "',SurveyType.LongName,'",') from SurveyType
UNION ALL
SELECT '0 as dummy FROM Sample,Operation WHERE Operation.SampleID=Sample.ID GROUP BY Sample.BuildingID'
```

Or, for Oracle and SQLite:

```
SELECT '  SELECT Sample.BuildingID,MAX(Sample.BuildingName_EN) BuildingID,'
UNION ALL
SELECT ' MAX(CASE WHEN Operation.SurveyTypeID='||SurveyType.I||' THEN Operation.StatusID ELSE " " END) AS "'||SurveyType.LongName||'",' from SurveyType
UNION ALL
SELECT '0 as dummy FROM Sample,Operation WHERE Operation.SampleID=Sample.ID GROUP BY Sample.BuildingID'
```

Comment: What you said it right.will take care of it.But what if i insert one more value in the surveytype column?

Comment: Well, unfortunately there is no non-programmatic way of doing this in pure SQL. I will update an answer with an workaround.

Comment: Trailing spaces in generated strings ensure ascending order of UNION ALL result

Comment: Error : no such function: concat

Comment: Sorry, you posted in MYSQL section, so I used MYSQL string concatenation function. Use || operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

I wont discuss the model itself but there is relation one to many **Sample[1]-[*]Operation**. 
So if you want to query all operations for sample in a SQL row you have to write subselects. 
This can only be done if thre is fixed amount of operations possible and I assume it is dynamic.

More common approach is to qyery relations with duplication od sample entry and process it in code

```
SELECT s.building_name, s.building_id, o.statusID 
from sample s, operation o
where s.id = o.sampleid
```

Other way is to select operations in separate query for given status.

```
SELECT o.statusID 
operation o
where o.sampleid  = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the data and unfortunately in mysql you cannot achieve this dynamically .

Try this:

```
SELECT
    s.BuildingName_EN as building_name,
    s.ID building_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN st.LongName = 'Survey1' THEN sa.ID ELSE 0 END) as Survey1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN st.LongName = 'Survey2' THEN sa.ID ELSE 0 END) as Survey2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN st.LongName = 'New Survey 3' THEN sa.ID ELSE 0 END) as 'New Survey 3'
FROM 
    Operation o
LEFT JOIN Sample s
    ON o.SampleID = s.ID 
LEFT JOIN Status sa
    ON o.StatusID = sa.ID 
LEFT JOIN SurveyType st
    ON o.SurveyTypeID = st.ID 
GROUP BY
    s.ID
```

Comment: please note i am using sqlite

Comment: it should be fine also in sqlite . "SQLite understands most of the standard SQL language." `SUM`,`IF`,`JOIN` and `GROUP BY` are all present in sqlite

Comment: lol it has `IFNULL` but not `IF`... I've update the query using `CASE` pls try it now

Answer (score 0):

```
For this first you have to join two tables like : Operation and Sample with SurveyType and then pivot the column 'LongName' of SurveyType. We can achieve it dynamically. 

Here is the query...



Select * FROM 
(Select Sample.BuildingName_EN AS 'Building Name', 
        Sample.BuildingID,
        SurveyType.LongName,
        Operation.StatusID 
from SurveyType
Inner Join Operation ON 
    Operation.SurveyTypeID = SurveyType.ID
Inner Join Sample ON
    Operation.SampleID = Sample.ID
    ) P
PIVOT
(
MAX(StatusID)
FOR LongName
IN ([Survey 1],[Survey 2],[New Survey 3])
) AS pvt
```